# How can I run a program with no user account control popup in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, controls, account

In the User Account Control, there is an option to set no user account control. This will use the rights of the root user, which I can not do because the root user is not allowed to run my program. So I have to set user account control to on. Now every time my program runs I get a user account control popup to allow the program to run. This is very annoying when I have to run the program 30 times in a row. Is there a way to auto accept so I don't get the popup if that program is running?

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not in favor of it for built-in security issues, depending on your situation, might it be a solution to programatically turn down/off UAC via regedt32, then run the procedure however many times needed, then reinitialize UAC when complete?

Comment: It is on the lowest setting without turning it off. The program is, that if I turn it off, the rights are set to the root user and can not run my program as root.